# single IP VPS - how to run apache / multiple nodejs on separate domains on port 80?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, haproxy, node.js

I know it isn't the optimal solution

I have several apache sites running on port 80 -  i wanted to a add a nodejs app - works fine on port 8000. 
I am using this setup

http://physalix.com/reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-in-production-with-apache2-haproxy-and-monit/

but it's pretty unstable - i was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this -

i am a beginner and was trying to get nginx working, unsuccessfully (got caught into errors about domain.crt and ssl and whatnot )

is there a concrete tutorial how to successfully balance and proxy all apps to port 80 - based on different domains and routes on different ports ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep using **apache2** not to break a working setup - it can operate in proxying mode using [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)

- **nginx** is not needed as you already have a working setup
- **haproxy** is an overkill here too

Here's an [article](http://blog.podrezo.com/making-node-js-work-with-apache/) describing a similar configuration